# How do I write in pyspark in an aws gluejob?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have this data in a DataFrame1:

| cust_no | cust_name | FIRST | SECOND | THIRD | FOURTH | FIFTH | SIXTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5432 | Smith | 0 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 3 | 0 |
| 3657 | John | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| 3562 | Rebecca | 7 | 0 | 9 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 9863 | Sam | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |

scorerules_df is:

| score_rule | value |
| --- | --- |
| score_rule1 | SECOND |
| score_rule2 | FOURTH |
| score_rule3 | FIRST |
| score_rule4 | THIRD |
| score_rule5 | SIXTH |

output_df should be like below:

| rule | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust_no | 5432 | 3657 | 3562 | 9863 |
| cust_name | Smith | John | Rebecca | Sam |
| score_rule1 | SECOND | NULL | NULL | SECOND |
| score_rule2 | FOURTH | NULL | FOURTH | NULL |
| score_rule3 | NULL | FIRST | FIRST | NULL |
| score_rule4 | THIRD | NULL | THIRD | NULL |
| score_rule5 | NULL | NULL | SIXTH | SIXTH |

Edit:

scorerules_df just says which column to consider for each scorerule. scorerule1 is 'SECOND'. So, if somebody's value in SECOND column is anything other than NULL, the column name i.e SECOND should be entered in output_df

Comment: how are `dataframe1` and `scorerules_df` related?

Comment: They're not. scorerules_df just says which column to consider for each scorerule. scorerule1 is 'SECOND'. So, if somebody's value in SECOND column is anything other than NULL, the column name i.e SECOND should be entered in output_df